# Recursion function for getting the supply locations

Tags: python

I have a `dictionary` in this format `destination location : list of supply locations` -

```
dict_input = {'A':['B'], 'B':['C','Y'], 'C':['D'], 'Y':['Z']}
```

For the destination location `'A'`, I want to find out the end supply locations in the supply chain (Locations `'D'` and `'Z'` in this case)

I have written a function like this -

```
def get_source(node):
    source = []
    if node in dict_input:
        next_node = dict_input[node]
                 source = [get_source(i) for i in next_node]
        return list(source)
    else:
        return node
```

When I execute the function - `print("The source is", get_source('A'))`, I get `The source is [[['D'], ['Z']]]`. Its a list within a list. Why I am getting the output that way? How to get output as `The source is ['D', 'Z']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List comprehension returns a list, and your hash entries are lists, which explains the nested result:

```
>>> [ get_source(i) for i in dict_input['A'] ]
[[['D'], ['Z']]]
```

You can use a list to accumulate the result and use the list comprehesion for just visiting all the nodes:

```
def get_source(n, acc=[]):
    if n in dict_input:
        [ get_source(i, acc) for i in dict_input[n] ]
    else:
        acc.append(n)
    return acc

>>> get_source('A', [])
['D','Z']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dict_input = {'A':['B'], 'B':['C','Y'], 'C':['D'], 'Y':['Z']}

def get_source(node):
    source = []
    if node in dict_input:
        next_node = dict_input[node]
        for i in next_node:
            source += get_source(i) # source.extend(get_source(i))

        return source
    else:
        return [node,] # just return node if output of get_source('Z') should be just 'Z' 


print(get_source('A')) #['D', 'Z']
print(get_source('B')) #['D', 'Z']
print(get_source('Z')) #['Z']
```

Comment: @Karvy1 you should visualize whats happening because of recursive call with list comprehension using http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit